# avoid refresh for mp3 player on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flash

I know there is a lot on this topic out there.  But, I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way to go about this.  I want an mp3 player stretched at the bottom of the screen that won't refresh on page reload.  I just want to embed a basic mp3 player in some flash, or use jquery, or ajax?  Not really sure.  I'm most familiar with jquery and would prefer that route.  I just not sure how you could have a div that stretches through every page, but only being defined in one page.  Any ideas on how to go about this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

About all you could do is use a frame - a horrible concept. This would let you have two completely independent areas in the window, and a refresh of the "content" frame wouldn't affect the "mp3" frame.

Comment: How do achieve the asynchronous frame approach.  I tried embeding:         <div id="mp3-player">
   <iframe width="960"  height="95" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="/themes/zen/templates/mp3-player.html">
   </iframe>
</div>  It loads fine, but, still reloads on page refresh/new page.  Is there something I'm missing here?  Or, is there a whole other thing to the asynchronous frame thing I'm not aware of?  Thank you.

Comment: No, an iframe is embedded within a page. When the page is reloaded, the iframe gets trashed/rebuilt along with it. That's why you have to use a full blown `<frameset>`/`<frame>` setup.